# I cannot get a response from uber auth

Tags: ruby, oauth, uber-api

I am trying to integrate Uber with my web app following their oauth guides. I currently have a redirect from my website to my server, where I make a request to `https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize` and get a 302. However, I am not ever getting a response back from uber with the `access_token` and `refresh_token`.

I have a server running at https://mobilius-app.herokuapp.com and a front-end at http://mobilius-website.herokuapp.com. I am currently sending a request to `https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize` with payload of

```
{
    'client_secret' => UBER_CLIENT_SECRET,
    'client_id' => UBER_CLIENT_ID,
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' => `https://mobilius-app.herokuapp.com/api/uber_tokens`,
    'code' => [the auth code]
  }
```

`https://mobilius-app.herokuapp.com/api/uber_tokens` never gets a response from uber with the auth token and refresh token, however. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First you should double check if you set the correct redirect url in the dashboard. 
Second your request to 'https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize' seems to contain invalid payload. Please follow the steps of the [authentication guide](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/introduction). Briefly, you need to:

- Send user to  authorize url
- Receive the redirect with a `authorization code`
- make a POST call to: `https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token`
- Store access and refresh token for future use